# Why does $(p)$ split in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ if and only if $X^2+1$ split modulo $p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to show that we may write $(p)=(p_1)(p_2)$, where $(p)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, if and only if $X^2+1$ splits into linear factors in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$.

I have the following isomorphism of rings:
$$\mathbb{Z}[i]/(p)\cong\mathbb{Z}[X]/(p,X^2+1)\cong\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(X^2+1).$$
Suppose, for example, that $X^2+1$ splits into linear factors mod $p$. Then
$$\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(X^2+1)\cong\mathbb{F}_p\oplus\mathbb{F}_p$$
via the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

So now I have $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(p)\cong\mathbb{F}_p\oplus\mathbb{F}_p$. If we take the map $\mathbb{Z}[i]\rightarrow\mathbb{F}_p\oplus\mathbb{F}_p$, I can take the kernel after composing with projection on the first and second coordinate to get two ideals $(p_1)$ and $(p_2)$. I se that $(p_1)\cap(p_2)=(p)$. But how do I show that they are comaximal?

Comment: Do you know that every nonzero prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is maximal?

Comment: @RichardD.James Ah, it seems like if $(p_1)$ and $(p_2)$ are different, then them being maximal implies the result. But can they be the same?

Comment: Look at the *ring structure* in each case.  The quotient ring $\mathbf Z[i]/(p)$ is a product of two fields if $p$ splits, a field if $p$ stays prime, and has a nonzero nilpotent element if $p$ is the square of a prime (just for the prime $2$). The quotient ring $\mathbf F_p[x]/(x^2+1)$ behaves in the same way when $x^2 + 1 \bmod p$ factors in analogous ways (reducible with distinct roots, irreducible, square of an irreducible).

Comment: @KCd That cleared things up, thanks!